# let user adjust region to be monitored

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit, geofencing, clregion

I would like to let a user to adjust a region to be monitored like the iOS 7 reminder app as shown on the attached image bellow.

I have created a rigion like:

`CLRegion *newRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:regionAnnotation.coordinate 
                      radius:100.0 
                  identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f",regionAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, regionAnnotation.coordinate.longitude]];
regionAnnotation.region = newRegion;`

Do we have a public api to let the user adjust the radius of this region?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sorts of things are usually easier if you don't think about the user control as part of the map. Instead, disable interaction with the map or put a transparent view over it, then show your control above that. Respond to changes in the control by adjusting the map programmatically. You can also make use of MapKit API for doing the pixel-to-distance conversions that are necessary for this.

Comment: Right, that is the direction that I am going now, I was going to answer my question once I am done. I was just wondering if Apple already have such API as part of there geo-fence library. thanks incanus for your response.